# How do I hide everything that overflows from the body?

Tags: css

I have an element that goes off the screen and makes the site wider and a scroll appears at the bottom so I tried to use `overflow: hidden;` on a `body` and instead of hiding everything off the page, it just locks the view at the first content that appears when the site loads and it's no longer possible to scroll down and see the other elements on the page

Comment: overflow-x:hidden ?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about that option, it works now

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-y: scroll`

```css
.scroll{
  border:solid 1px #343434;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='scroll'>
Text<br>
Text<br>
Text<br>
Text<br>
Text<br>
Text<br>
Text<br>
Text<br>
Text<br>
<div>
```